# changing part of an object name in maya python

Tags: python, rename, maya

I feel like this should be easy but all of my searching has been in vain.

I'm in maya, I have a series of objects who's names end with _LOC i want to run a python script that renames them to end with _JNT instead. I managed to get it to work on a single object, but my for loop just does the first object and then stops. Here's what i have so far:

```
import maya.cmds as mc

sel=mc.ls(selection=True)

for each in sel:
    item=sel[0]
    newname=item.split('_')
    mc.rename(newname[0]+'_JNT')
```

Comment: in the `for`-loop you define `each` but you don't use it, try changing `item=sel[0]` to `item=each[0]`

Comment: davewards is right and I think it would be even easier to do each.replace('_LOC', '_JNT')

Answer (score 2):

You're not actually using your loop.  You just need to use the loop variable `each` where you're currently referencing the selection:

```
import maya.cmds as mc

sel=mc.ls(selection=True)

for each in sel:
    newname=each.split('_')
    mc.rename(newname[0]+'_JNT')
```

Answer (score 1):

Since maya.cmds work with strings the same way mel does, the script can fail if you rename the parent of a child node because the full name of the child changes in Maya but not in the selection list. It depends a lot on your setup.

I recommend to use pymel instead because it relies on MObjects and not on strings:

```
import pymel.core as pm

sel=pm.ls(selection=True)

for each in sel:
    newname=each.nodeName().replace("_LOC", "_JNT")
    each.rename(newname)
```

Comment: You can also use `OpenMaya.MDagPath` when using `cmds` to work with pointers instead of a string.

Answer (score 0):

Others have correctly addressed the error in your code.

Maya also has a built-in tool to do this, under **Modify -> Search and Replace Names**. It does exactly what your code is doing. It also has the ability to replace all names in a scene, or just your selection.